# Need help on ajax and jquery search form in django

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-templates, django-forms

I written a search form using ajax and jquery,here i am trying to submit a form with user ,start_date and end_date.

here user = q
     start_date =q1
     end_date =q2

search code :

```
    {% extends 'newbase.html' %}

{% block extra_js %}
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( '#searchSubmit' ).click( function() {
    q = $( '#q' ).val();
    $( '#search_results').html( '&nbsp;' ).load( '/myapp/results_search/?q=' + q +'&q1='+ q1 +'&q2='+q2 );
  });
});

$( document ).ajaxStart( function() {
  $( '#spinner' ).show();
}).ajaxStop( function() {
  $( '#spinner' ).hide();
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<center>

<div>

   <input id="q" type="text"/>
   <input id="q1" type="text"/>
   <input id="q2" type="text"/>

  <input id="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
  <br/>
  <span class="hint">Type in a  user &  Dates to search </span>
  <div class="margin">
    <span id="spinner"><img src="/media/img/spinner.gif"/></span>
    <div id="search_results"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

In view.py

```
def user_search(request):
  data = {
     }
  return render_to_response('manager/attendance_search.html', data,
                               context_instance = RequestContext(request)) 


def results_search(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      q = request.GET.get( 'q' )
      start=request.GET.get( 'q1')
      end=request.GET.get( 'q2' )
      if q is not None:            
        results = MyTable.objects.filter(at_user=q,at_date__gte=start,at_date__lte=end)
        data = {
                'results': results,
            }
        return render_to_response( 'search_results.html', data, 
                                       context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**My questions are:**

- After giving dates and user names it
  doesn't return any results ?
- How to    added multiple args in ajax
  like ?q=q    & q1=q1 & q2=q2  in
  jquery function?
- how to get values from request.GET.get and pass to ORM ?

if i do only user search by editing this line it gives output

Below changes works

```
  $( '#search_results').html( '&nbsp;' ).load( '/myapp/results_search/?q=' + q );
```

in view.py

```
 def results_search(request):
       if request.is_ajax():
          q = request.GET.get( 'q' )

          if q is not None:            
            results = MyTable.objects.filter(at_user=q)
            data = {
                    'results': results,
                }
            return render_to_response( 'search_results.html', data, 
                                           context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

but here single search is working,if i added multiple args its not working.

Am i doing anything wrong   in request.GET.get

Please need help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it on my own,i forgot to add below lines to scripts,this values are going empty.Now i am getting search results

q1 = $('#q1').val();
q2 = $('#q2').val();